# How to reconnect a JMS connector after a regular interval

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

Requirement :- A JMS Connector with a Oracle AQ as inbound endpoint.

Problem statement :- How to reconnect a JMS connector after a regular interval so that when it reconnect it consumes the new messages in queue.

I have tried the below reconnect strategy

```
-- JMS Connector defined
        <jms:connector name="AQJMS" validateConnections="true"
            maxRedelivery="-1" numberOfConsumers="1" durable="true" doc:name="JMS"
            username="X" password="X" connectionFactory-ref="OAQTopicConnectionFactoryBean">
-- reconnect at 5 sec
            <reconnect-forever frequency="5000"/>
        </jms:connector>
-- flow
        <flow name="sendmessagetoqFlow">
-- jms inbound endpoint as oracle AQ
            <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="QUEUE"
                connector-ref="AQJMS" doc:name="AQJMS">
                <jms:client-ack-transaction action="BEGIN_OR_JOIN"/>
            </jms:inbound-endpoint>
            <logger message="Log 1 - #[message.inboundProperties]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger 1"/>
        </flow>
```

But its not reconnecting after 5 seconds.
    Could you please help me solve the problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: a jms inbound-endpoint receives messages as soon as they are available. it is not necessary to poll a queue like it is with a database.

Comment: i was expecting the same result as u have explained but with the code snippet i am not getting results , suppose application is running in  mule studio and i insert a message in back-end queue that message is not consumed until i restart the requester(jms inbound endpoint).

Comment: I tested your config with ActiveMQ as I don't have Oracle AQ in my system and I have inserted the message from ActiveMQ portal at the backend and found it working without any issue. I also tested the connection with disconnecting the ActiveMQ server. I found everything is working fine with ActiveMQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Configuring Transactional Polling (Enterprise)**
This works for me

```
    <jms:connector ...cut...>
         <service-overrides transactedMessageReceiver="com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jms.TransactedPollingJmsMessageReceiver" />
    </jms:connector>

    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="my.queue">
 <ee:multi-transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" timeout="30000"/>
         <properties>
              <spring:entry key="pollingFrequency" value="5000" /> 
         </properties>
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>
```

Comment: i have added the below code in the jms connector , <service-overrides transactedMessageReceiver="com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jms.T‌​ransactedPollingJmsM‌​essageReceiver" /> and changed the transaction type as muti resource transaction in jms endpoint , now its working but after consuming the message from queue exception is thrown as JMS-131: Session is closed